# Symfony ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS It works if I rename the route

Tags: php, symfony, server

I am trying to call this route (/invoices). However, I get from the browser the message "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". I not have any other rounds with the name (/invoices). The other rounds work correctly. The problem appeared suddenly.

I have also cleared my browser cache and cookies, but without success.

It works if I rename the route.

```
/**
 * @Route("/invoices", methods={"GET"})
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
 */
public function index(): Response
{
    
    return $this->renderTemplate('invoice/index.html.twig',[
        'SiteName' => "Invoices",
        'NavName' => 'Invoices',
        'BreadcrumbPath' => $breadcrumbPath
    ]);
}
```

[image]

//edit add server config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.de
ServerAlias www.domain.de

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
DirectoryIndex /index.php

<Directory /var/www/html/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from All
    FallbackResource /index.php
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/public/bundles>
    DirectoryIndex disabled
    FallbackResource disabled
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.de [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.de
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: See if `bin/console debug:router` offers any clues.  Maybe you have another route which matches GET /invoices?

Comment: @Cerad I have checked the routes with the suggested command. However there is only one route with /invoices.

Comment: Have you tried `php bin/console cache:clear`? Strange if you have no other routes, also is that the full code for your index function?

Comment: Do you have a redirect in you webserver (apache, nginx, e.g. in .htaccess) ? As symfony by defaults redirects requests with trailing slashes (https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/routing.html#redirecting-urls-with-trailing-slashes) your webserver may have a config for this route the other way around.

Comment: @Bossman I have also cleared the cache but without success. And yes this is my code. It is a new route with an empty template.

Comment: @yvesb I found the cause through your input. In the public folder there is a folder named invoices. The folder is named exactly the same as my route. After I renamed this folder my controller was called.